# 1500 new API in iOS sdk 4?

Tags: api, ios4

Apple describes iOS SDK 4 contains over 1,500 new APIs.

Such as

1.Calendar Access

2.Video Playback & Capture

3.In-App SMS

4.Map Kit Improvements

5.Photo Library Access

6.Quick Look

I am wondering what are the other APIs available i.e. the missing 1494 APIs.

Comment: perhaps you should ask this on the proper site... http://stackapps.com/

Comment: @CrazyDart - why stackapps.com ?

Comment: @CrazyDart No, stackapps.com is for apps that access the StackExchange API. It has nothing (directly) to do with mobile apps.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was for all APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 1500 is more a marketing number that includes all new classes, functions etc, not only new frameworks and old frameworks enhancements